# Adding Facebook Like-button to the User menu in the top-right corner

Tags: 7, routes

Do you think there is a way to make [a Facebook Like-button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) appear in the **User menu** of Drupal 7, right besides the **My Profile** and **Logout** links?

**UPDATE:** I'd like to add the button for [my site](http://preferans.de) and the **User menu** seems to be the best place.

Comment: Why do you need it in amongst the menu items? Im guessing you will need a menu hook if that is what you would like to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to adding the like-button in the actual link items, maybe you should consider add it via a block or similar above/below your menu.

Checkout the [Facebook social plugins integration](http://drupal.org/project/fb_social) module.